# Как реализовать вывод лога на форме WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть форма. Нужно выводить лог по ходу выполнения программы. Вопрос, как это сделать? Если я привяжу TextBox к переменной типа `string`, то при обновлении будет перепечатана строка полностью. Думаю, будет не очень хорошо, когда накопится много строк :)

Но `ObservableCollection<string>` `TextBox` не съест. Да и смысла в этом бы не было. Какой нибудь `ItemsControl` мне тоже не нужен, потому что нужна возможность выделять текст.

На первое время я обойдусь таки TextBox + string, но хотелось бы узнать про ваш опыт вывода логов.

Comment: ItemsControl с TextBox на каждую строку например?

Comment: Если логов немного, можно ещё какой то RichTextBox попробовать, хотя на больших объемах по моему не сгодится.

Comment: ListBox, ну и прикрутить контекстное меню копирования строки

Comment: @Monk, текст должен выделяться свободно, поэтому `ItemsControl` не подойдет. RichTextBox в принципе не нужен, потому что текст я форматировать не собираюсь.

Comment: @iRumba: А к чему требование, чтобы текст свободно выделялся? Это резко ограничивает размер файла и создаёт тормоза.

Answer (score 1):

Выводить можно через `DataGrid`. Есть и колонки и текст из ячеек можно копировать.

А вообще вариантов много. Можно использовать `ListBox`, можно даже `ComboBox`. Последний мало места занимает, а открыть можно большой список. Вот только скопировать не получится. Разве что, если при выборе строки ее сразу в буфер обмена копировать.

Если используете какой-то не самописный логгер, то можно посмотреть на сайте у них, может есть примеры вывода на форму. Так у [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), есть [примеры](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30795/C-WPF-Log-Net-Viewer) и для WPF и WinForm.

Comment: Я думал, что это очевидно :( Текст должен выделяться свободно, а не в пределах одной ячейки. По поводу листбокса я же написал `Какой нибудь ItemsControl мне тоже не нужен`.

Answer (score 0):

Один из простейших вариантов это асинхронно сохранять лог в файл и потом просто открывать его либо периодически по таймеру либо по ссылке (меню).

Можно легко и быстро использовать [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial) для этого.

Вот тут просто все изложено https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnG_8fk77gY

Код примера для Visual Studio 2017 тут https://github.com/DmitryBoyko/Lessons/tree/master/CSharp/Lesson1/WindowsFormsApp

Если вам нужно выводить лог динамично прямо на форму, то тогда вам нужно настроить target для NLog.

Удачи!