# C# .NET как лучше логировать в консольном приложении

Tags: c#, логирование, best-practice, nlog, log4net

Хочу написать нормальное консольное приложение, которое не стыдно будет выложить в общее пользование. Встал вопрос о логировании. Мне не надо каких-то там серьезных вещей, типа базы данных для логов или XML файлов. Я думаю писать обычный `*.log` файл.

Вот только не знаю что лучше использовать: NLog, log4net или ещё что-то?

Мне не нужно миллион настроек. Просто хочу чтобы из всех классов в программе писалось в один файл с указанием времени, даты, уровня логирования, метода и сообщения (стандартный набор)

Что посоветуете, чтобы было не стыдно потом логи показывать?

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527930/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5-wpf/712611#712611

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю, что там с Log4net, но NLog удовлетворяет всем вышеперечисленным требованиям. Можете смело использовать данную библиотеку.

Comment: плюсану за NLog

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вам поможет вот этот пост http://academyofprogrammer.blogspot.ru/2017/08/nlog-winforms.html

Вы можете посмотреть видео об использовании NLog в WinForms на русском языке.

Мануал на английском тут https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial

Удачи!